# Alternative of fzero function

Tags: matlab, function

Let us consider following code in MATLAB:

```
f=inline('x.^4-29*x.^2-132','x')  
f =
     Inline function:
     f(x) = x.^4-29*x.^2-132

x=fzero(f,-5.5)
x =
  -5.744562646538029

f(x)
ans =
     0
```

There  fzero works fine, but for following code

```
g=inline('x^2','x')
g =
     Inline function:
     g(x) = x^2

h=fzero(g,-1.3)
Exiting fzero: aborting search for an interval containing a sign change
    because NaN or Inf function value encountered during search.
(Function value at 1.5776e+154 is Inf.)
Check function or try again with a different starting value.

h =
   NaN
```

This result is returned, how can I fix it? Should I introduce some tolerance or is there another method in MATLAB?

Comment: `fzero` is used for functions which change its sign in a certain interval. The documentation clearly says, [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fzero.html#btoc6lj-10), that, "`x = fzero(fun,x0)` tries to find a point `x` where `fun(x) = 0`. This solution is where `fun(x)` changes sign. `fzero` cannot find a root of a function such as `x^2`".

Comment: i know this,so my question is what is alternative way

Comment: I thought you are trying to use `fsolve` to get a solution for your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fzero is able to find roots with sign change, others are not found.

If available use the symbolic toolbox:

```
syms x
w=x.^4-29*x.^2-132
solve(w)
v=x^2
solve(v)
```

Answer (score 4):

You could also use [`fminsearch`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/fminsearch.html):

```
x=fminsearch(@(x) abs(x^2),-5.5)
x =    
   4.4409e-15

x=fminsearch(@(x) abs(x.^4-29*x.^2-132),-5.5)    
x =    
   -5.7446
```

Answer (score 3):

And just to complete this line of answers, there is [`roots`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/roots.html). It works for polynomials and gives you all possible solutions (including the complex ones).

```
f = [1 0 -29 0 -132];   %// x^4 + 0x^3 -29x^2 + 0x -132
roots(f)    
ans =
  -5.7446          
   5.7446          
   0.0000 + 2.0000i     %// Funny coincidence
   0.0000 - 2.0000i
```

And now for the other example (note that `x^2 = 0` has a double root at `x = 0`:

```
f = [1 0 0];            %// x^2 + 0x + 0  
roots(f)
ans =
     0
     0
```

And just for fun, `x^2 = -1`:

```
f = [1 0 1];
roots(f)
ans =
        0 + 1.0000i
        0 - 1.0000i
```